# p-multiselect placeholder change

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to change the placeholder of p-multiselect. When all the options are selected I want to show 'All' and when only few are selected then use '# selected'. I have this string values in a variable (selectedNumCols) and tried to bind it with both placeholder and defaultLabel in following ways but neither worked.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="columnsForTable" [(ngModel)]="scrollableCols" optionsLabel="label" [placeholder]="selectedNumCols"></p-multiSelect>
```

OR

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="columnsForTable" [(ngModel)]="scrollableCols" optionsLabel="label" [defaultLabel]="selectedNumCols"></p-multiSelect>
```

How do I solve this?

P.S. - Please dis-regard any syntax error, there are no syntax error in original code.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `selectedItems` template for `<p-multiselect>`.

1. If all options are selected (`countries.length == value?.length ?? 0`), use `#allSelectedTemplate`.
2. If condition *1* fails, switch to `#elseTemplate`. Validate if there is any item(s) selected, if true, use the nested `<ng-template>`.
3. If condition *2* fails, switch to `#defaultTemplate`.

```
<p-multiSelect
  [options]="countries"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries"
  placeholder="Select a Country"
  optionLabel="name"
  class="multiselect-custom"
>
  <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItems">
    <div
      *ngIf="
        countries.length == value?.length ?? 0;
        then allSelectedTemplate;
        else elseTemplate
      "
    ></div>

    <ng-template #allSelectedTemplate> All </ng-template>

    <ng-template #elseTemplate>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="value?.length ?? 0 > 0" [ngIfElse]="defaultTemplate"
        >{{ value?.length ?? 0 }} selected
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #defaultTemplate>Select Countries</ng-template>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

*Provided a similar demo according to your requirement*.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-nnggvn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

**Reference**

[PrimeNG Multiselect (Template Mode demo)](http://primefaces.org/primeng/multiselect)